# Android Split and TextUtils.split not working when assigning to private array

Tags: android, arrays, string, split

okay so in my other android activity I have it display a button on the screen if a certain string is in the array. I will be using the split function on a stored string to turn my string back into an array and then assinging that array into my private favorites array. In this example I am trying to get it to display a button if the string "UltimateBP" is in the private array favorites.

if i assign it directly using:
favorites[1]="UltimateBP";

it works and the button shows up correctly.
however if I assign it using the method below. it will not show up.

It does the same thing when I use the TextUtils split() method.

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application{

    private String mStringValue;
    private int numOfFavorites=1;
    private  String[] favorites = new String[150];


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {        
        mStringValue = "SavageLook.com";
        favorites[0] = "None";


        String someWords = "UltimateBP|Orange|Yellow";  
        String aColors[] = someWords.split("\\|");
        numOfFavorites++;
        String X = aColors[0];
        favorites[1]=X;

        super.onCreate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
String aColors[] = someWords.split("\\|");
```

You just need to show "|" like:

```
String aColors[] = someWords.split("|");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Paresh, but that doesnt seem to be the problem. Searching around on forums Ive found | is a reserved character so you need "//|". Regardless I have tried it with other characters such as "-" and "," and "." without the "//". still no luck.

Comment: *meant to say without the "\\".

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky What! are you sure? Check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Agree. using | as separator just splits the string into tokens one letter each